# Postgres - Extract latest record from historical data for each entity that meets specific criteria

Tags: postgresql, grouping, aggregate-functions

I have an asset_history table that looks like this...

```
asset_id   |          timestamp        |    sites           |
    1            2019-02-02 09:10:01         null
    1            2019-02-02 09:10:00     [{"id":2},{"id":3}]
    2            2019-02-02 10:00:01     [{"id":2},{"id":3}]
    2            2019-02-02 10:00:00          null
    3            2019-02-02 10:00:02          null
    3            2019-02-02 10:00:01          null
    3            2019-02-02 10:00:00      [{"id":3}]
    4            2019-02-02 11:00:00      [{"id":2}]
```

I want to write a SQL query that will give me the latest record from this table for each asset only if 'sites' is null on the latest record for the asset
The output from the above table that I'm looking for would be

```
asset_id   |          timestamp        |    sites           |
    1            2019-02-02 09:10:01         null
    3            2019-02-02 10:00:02         null
```

I would also like to know the total number of assets wherein the latest entry on each asset has sites as null and the time difference between the current time and timestamp on the latest entry where sites is null is greater than 1 hour.
So assuming current time is 2019-02-02 10:30:00, the resultset would look like this... (Since only asset_id 1 has a time difference of greater than 1 hour compared to current time)

```
|  count   |
     1
```